# How do you give a class in the controller the ID's it belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

How do i give my products the user_id, Location_id and the product_dates_id in the controller?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :product_date
end
```

**My Controller:**

```
def new
    @location = Location.new
    @product = Product.new
    product_date = @location.product_dates.build
    product_date.products.build
end

def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])
end
```

**My Table:**

```
create_table :products do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :location_id
      t.integer :product_date_id
end
```

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question

```
def new
    #First create the new product object assuming you have a current_user available. If not you will need to make a current_)user available.
    @product = current_user.build_product
    #Now build a new location for the product
    location = @product.build_location # You don't need location to be an instance variable.
    #when you reference @location in your form you should now be using fields_for :locations instead.
    #build a new product_date object for the location_product_dates array
    product_date = @location.product_dates.build
    #Now add that product date object to the product
    product.product_date = product_date
end
```

Add accepts_nested_attributes declarations to the relevant models and use fields_for declarations in the relevant product forms, that way your create and update actions don't need any changes to them as the fields_for declarations in the form will arrange for the related objects to have their data nested inside the products hash when posted back to the create and update actions.

Couple that with the accepts_nested_attributes_for declarations for all the right models and everything will automagically be updated/created

That answers you question. The new action builds all the records and sets up all the associations for you but it seems to me like you don't really need the product_date associated to the product as it is already associated to the location which is associated to the product and as a location can have many products (assumption based on your original new action) you would struggle to work out which product_date from the many location records and their associated product_date records should be added directly to the product.

I guess you have you associations slightly wrong.

You should also consider refactoring that new action into a class method on the product model to enable you to do something like

```
@product = Product.new_with_associations(current_user)
```

The def self.new_with_associations needs to just do pretty much exactly the same as the code I gave you for the new action but you will need to pass the current_user in as a param as the session hash (which is where the current_user will ultimately be coming from) is unavailable to models for very good reason.

Putting this in a class method for the product not only cleans up your controller code but also makes makes the code re-usable and simpler to test both from the console and from your test suite

Answer (score 2):

```
@location = Location.create(params[:location])
@location.products.each{ |p| p.update_attribute :user_id, current_user.id }
@location.product_dates.map(&:products).flatten.each{ |p| p.update_attribute :user_id, current_user.id }
```

or better add hidden field for `:user_id` into each product and product_date